# How do I find an ID in a file?

Tags: linux

I have a text file called ID.txt that contains the following:

Here is a list of some ID's

```
b028888
c039481
b016396
c456039
```

Lets see if this stupid thing will work!

I am wanting to run a command that will search that file for the b-id's or c-id's. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for grep.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your data file is testdata.txt. You can use following commands to get IDs with **b** or **c**.

```
 sed -n '/^b/p' testdata.txt

 sed -n '/^c/p' testdata.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$ grep "^[bc][0-9]\{6\}" filename
```

Comment: Anytime you start typing `cat...` if you are not actually *concatenating* two (or more) files together, then there is probably a more proper way to do what you are attempting... and you are likely committing a ***UUOc*** (*Unnecessary Use Of* `cat`). Perhaps `grep "^[bc]" filename` would work as well, while also avoiding the creation of an additional subshell required for each `'|'`. Just a thought.

Comment: I was not aware of **UUOc**, thank you for the explanation. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: I did the grep "^[bc]" and it did work. The cat was excess that was not needed. Say I run across a file that has extra incomplete id's like b12 and c34. I am wanting to capture the complete id's only. which contain either a b or c followed by the 6 numbers.

Comment: With the $ grep "^[bc][0-9]\{6\}" filename, it didn't grab the full ID's, it only grabbed the first 6 ID's and nothing else.

Comment: In the previous comment, you said complete ID's are consisted of a b/c and 6 numbers. Could you edit your question with a sample input/output?

Comment: I utilized the $ grep "^[bc][0-9]\{6\}" command, and it only pulled the first 6 listed ID's, even if they were incomplete ID's. It is as if the script pulled the first 6, rather than matching a pattern of the ID's requiring the b/c plus 6 characters.

Comment: So I was able to get the script working better. But if I have a few ID's on the same line, it is only displaying the first match on that line, then going to the next line. So it isn't grabbing all of the ID's. Any suggestions?